# How do you get rid of the notification to login to iCloud in System Preferences?

Tags: macos, icloud, preferences, monterey

If you want to login to MacOS to be able to get apps for example, but don't want (or can't due to corporate firewall, etc) to login to Icloud, how do you disable the red notification in system preferences?

Answer (score 5):

Clicking on the "Start using iCloud" button, and then cancelling it, removes the notification. At this time, on Monterey, it works and survives a reboot.

If you have already done this, and instead are presented with an Apple ID request, you must quit System Preferences (Command+Q) to get back to the main Apple ID control panel (with overview, Name, Phone, Email, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Just found a way without having to actually activate and cancel

Simply follow the procedure, even enter your Apple ID and password, but then **when prompted to enter the laptop password just fail to do so** by closing the window or hitting cancel, and voila, badge is gone